# C program not adding float correctly

Tags: c, floating-point, addition

I have a method that looks like this:

```
float * mutate(float* organism){   
    int i;
    float sign = 1;
    static float newOrg[INPUTS] = {0};

    for (i = 0;i<INPUTS;i++){
        if (rand() % 2 == 0) {
            sign = 1;
        } else {
            sign = -1;
        }
        float temp = (organism[i] + sign);
        printf("bf: %f af: %f diff: %f sign: %f sign2: %f temp: %f\n\n",
            organism[i], (organism[i] + sign), (organism[i] + sign)-organism[i],
            sign, sign+sign, temp);
        newOrg[i] = organism[i] + sign;
    }

    return newOrg;
}
```

When `sign` is not 0 the first two `"%f"`s are the same and the 3rd is 0, also putting the sum in a variable didn't help. This is baffling me! I can post full code if needed.

Output:

```
bf: 117810016.000000 af: 117810016.000000 diff: 0.000000 sign: 1.000000 sign2: 2.000000 temp: 117810016.000000
```

Comment: What are the values of `organism[]`? It would have helped to see a line of output. Perhaps you don't have precision to add/subtract 1.

Comment: When `sign` is not zero? But `sign` is *never* zero...

Comment: If the input values are very large, adding or subtracting 1 won't make any difference, and `(organism[i] + sign)-organism[i]` will be equal to `organism[i] - organism[i]`.

Comment: Why are you using floats ? It seems that this code performs integer operations

Comment: This method is going to be adapted quite a bit to mutate in more advanced ways.
Example output has been added. It sometimes does work I have just noticed, but not always.

Comment: That's great you've added the output, but the input is still missing. How do you call `mutate`?

Comment: I have changed it to double precision and it is now working! Thank you!

Comment: C does not support _methods_, only _functions_.

Comment: The C spec uses the the word _method_ to describe various aspects of C.  Perhaps C spec is not using _method_ as describe by some other language.  But since this post is only tagged `C`, the word _method_ is best understood in the generic sense [example](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/method) and not some other language's definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finite precision of `float`.

A typical `float` can only represent about 2<sup>32</sup> different numbers.  117,810,016.0 and 1.0 are two of them.  117,810,017.0 is not.  So the C sum of `117810016.0 + 1.0` results in the "best" answer of `117810016.0`.

Using a higher precision type like `double` often will extend the range of +1 exact math, but even that will not be exact with large enough values  (typically about 9.0*10e<sup>15</sup> or 2<sup>53</sup>).

If code is to retain using `float`, suggest limiting `organism[i]` to values to the inclusive range or ±8,388,608.0 (2<sup>23</sup>).

Perhaps can code simply use integer types for this task like `long long`.

Comment: I think the answer would be clearer if it focused on the numbers of bits in the mantissa/significand rather than for the entire floating-point number.

Comment: @njuffa I find if someone has a post like this, the details of mantissa/significand do not add clarity and prefer an answer that does not delve into `float` mechanics.  So I use the [pigeon hole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) here. Perhaps someone will post another answer based on the numbers of bits in the mantissa/significand for OP to select.

Comment: Currently, the answer *indirectly* references the number of mantissa bits by giving a range of ±8,388,608.0 for `float`, but without explaining where that limit comes from. Understanding the *general principle* would likely be helpful to future readers.